How should token refresh operations be performed in Asynchronous and Batch?
How should token refresh operations be performed in Asynchronous and Batch?
There are Batch and Asynchronous services in my spring boot projects. Since transactions take a long time, the token may expire. How is token refresh management done in these transactions?
How should the token refresh process be managed?
I could not find a topic with detailed best practices regarding this problem.

A batch should be using client credentials flow.
Refresh token flow is for refreshing tokens obtained with authorization code flow. Access tokens obtained with client credentials are not "refreshed", you just get new ones using client credentials again.
If a batch is initiated with the context of a user (a user authenticates using authorization code flow and then sends a query that initiates the batch), then user authorization should be evaluated when this query is received (you don't want to use the batch resources if the user isn't authorized to see the result), the necessary user data being passed to the batch as parameter (stuff like user subject and email).
If the batch needs to collaborate with other services, it is authorized as itself (not on behalf of the user) with tokens obtained with client credentials.
